# Converting Java String object into Json using Gson library

Tags: java, json, gson

I am able to convert the complex Java objects like **List**, **ArrayList** etc containing huge volume of data into **Json** efficiently using the **Gson** library as below code

```
    List<CusPojo> list=new ArrayList<CusPojo>();
       .
       .
     Gson gson=new Gson();
     String json=gson.toJson(list);
```

But if if try the same for a **String literal** or a **String Obj**, the conversion is not happening

```
    String msg="success";
            **or**
    String msg=new String("success");

    Gson gson=new Gson();
    String json=gson.toJson(msg); 
    System.out.println("json data-- "+json);
```

Here i expect the data in Json format like

```
    json data-- {"msg":"success"}
```

but instead  **success** is what i am getting

```
    json data-- "success"
```

I couldn't find any explanation regarding this particulary
Please help , thank you in advance..

Comment: If you want your json output to be {"msg": "success"} try using a class, with a string named msg.

Comment: can please give me and example?

Comment: Or put the string in a map with the key "msg"

Comment: How can gson know that your variable is called "msg"? What would you expect it to print if the parameter were `msg + msg`?

Comment: @LionelPort brings up a good point, you can use a map as well, I think.

Comment: @Nishi, your String msg, is merely named msg, the value of it has no concept of what it is named.

Comment: Same reason your list example doesn't give `{"list": [...data here...]}`

Answer (score 3):

Please note, I rarely write java anymore, and I don't have a compiler in front of me, so there could be some obvious bugs here. But try this.

Assuming you have a class for example:

```
public class Test {
    public String msg;
}
```

You can use it, rather than a string in your gson example.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.msg = "success"
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(test);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For simple cases where you don't want to use a POJO or map you can just create a [JsonObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) where it's behaviour is close to a map so you can pass the string as value and provide a property name where the JsonObject's `toString()` will be in JSON format. So you could do the following:

```
JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject();
jObj.addProperty("msg", msg);
System.out.println(jObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

GSon doesn't save you variable name, it saves field name of serialized class

```
public class StringSerialize{
      private String msg;
      ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong.
your variable msg is just holding the data.
try this, let me know if it helps

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();       
    map.put("msg", "success");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(map);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("msg", "success");
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(m));
```

**Result**

```
{"msg":"success"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for your example:
At first create a model class

```
class Model {
    public String msg;
}
```

The name of your member is the key in your json

```
public static void main() {
    Model model = new Model();
    model.msg = "success"
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = gson.toJson(test); // Model to json
    Model result = gson.fromJson("{\"msg\":\"success\"}", Model.class) // json to Model
}
```

This is a very good [gson-tutorial](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction.jsp) linked by the gson repository on github